# Detecting disconnected client side socket connection (cross-platform applicability)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I know there are hundreds of answers for this question, but I cannot get it done with respect to my situation. The scenario is like this, we have a server written in TCP/IP protocol, we have multiple clients connected to this server. The client here is a software module which before starting on a client machine, registers its presence in the server and loads the functionalities. But the problem is that this software module getting crashed and there by no `socket.close()` is called, this will make its footprints still present in the server even though its crashed. How to recognize this?

I am using `select()` method in the client to notify any info from client and server (vice-versa)
 I cannot create a process separately for each client request in the server, neither can I create a parent-child mechanism in the client machine.
 `tcp-keepalive` is not applicable as we need to tweak the registry in Windows? I need a x-platform compatible solution.
I have read that `recv()` to the connected socket in the server code will return some values from 'that' client such as `0` for socket closed? Can I use this to clear off the client socket registration in the server database? Will this work?

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what method you are using to handle socket events in your server side code. Whatever method for polling your sockets you are using, `recv()` will return 0 or *possibly* -1/`SOCKET_ERROR` when a client crashes.

To detect inactive client connections most server applications send out some form of heartbeat or ping message periodically within the application layer protocol. When an ACK fails to be sent from the client the server application will then get notification the client disconnected via `recv()` returning 0 or `SOCKET_ERROR` with an error code of something like `WSAENETRESET`, `WSAECONNABORTED`, `WSAETIMEDOUT`, or `WSAECONNRESET` (see the various error codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx)). Often after the server sends the heartbeat to a client TCP port that is no longer active an ICMP packet is sent in response that will alert your server that the port or host not active (`recv()` will immediately notify you of this event).

If you wish to turn the TCP keep alive timer on you can use the socket option [SO_KEEPALIVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551(v=vs.85).aspx). The interval can also be set using [SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220(v=vs.85).aspx).

Edit: Keep in mind the various error codes and option SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS are Win32 specific. To handle these events for other operating systems you will need to use operating specific ways of retrieving error codes and setting the TCP keep alive interval if you choose to do so. My best suggestion to keeping your code cross platform compatible is to simply implement an application layer heartbeat message into your protocol or some other application layer specific timeout. Doing so will allow you to forget about managing TCP keep alives.

#### Update

I cannot comment on EJP's answer, but it's important to point out that by calling `send()` he is effectively recommending you implement a heartbeat/ping message in the application layer of your protocol. While checking the return value of `send()` is important, if you are polling/selecting read events you will be notified of the TCP connection being disconnected immediately upon calling `recv()` the moment the connection is deemed broken by the TCP stack. If you wait for your application timer to try to send some data using `send()` that could be many seconds (depending on the length of your interval timer) after `recv()` has already notified you that the connection is broken. In other words: pay attention to the `recv()` return values as well as your `send()` return values.

Comment: As a matter of fact most servers don't do that at all. Most servers are HTTP servers, and there is conspicuously no ping in the HTTP protocol. When an ACK fails to be received, `recv()` will not return zero.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, you are incorrect on both points. All well known HTTP servers have internal timeouts that disconnect sockets after some period of inactivity. If a response is sent to the client that crashed and an ACK is not sent back in response, recv() will return 0/-1 because of either an ICMP error or the builtin TCP timers that will eventually timeout from the related TCP PSH sent from the server.

Comment: HTTP servers have idle timeouts, and I have not stated otherwise, but they do not ping their clients. I am not so much recommending a ping protocol as pointing out that if in the normal course of events you do enough sends you will dtpetect a disconnect.

Comment: @EJP you are correct, but I never said HTTP servers ping their clients - you brought up HTTP (which is one protocol out of a vast sea of protocols). How can you do "enough sends" if you are not sending pings/heartbeats (since you are assuming HTTP is the protocol and the client has crashed)? Quite honestly you seem like you're attacking my post just to attack it as your comments are not rational.

Comment: @Brandon thanks for the answer, any example to show how heartbeat sig works?

Comment: @KyleReese A heartbeat can be as simple as every 30 seconds send a small packet to all the connected sockets (preferably specifying a message type that is ignored by the clients). It all depends on the protocol that you are using however. A simple way to do this using select() is to set the timeout on select() to something like 1 second, then have a time variable that keeps track of the time a new heartbeat should be sent out. When the current time is greater than the heartbeat time send out a heartbeat to all the clients. This causes any broken connections to eventually return 0/-1 on recv().

Comment: @KyleReese I should add that by generating heartbeat messages at a low interval like once every 30 seconds you'll also have a better chance keeping clients that are behind NAT/firewalls connected.

Comment: You are evading the issue. Your answer states 'most server applications send out some form of heartbeat or ping message periodically'. HTTP doesn't do that, and that 'most' servers are HTTP servers.

Comment: @EJP Why do you keep talking about HTTP? Most servers/daemons do not use HTTP and I'm not sure why you keep saying that. Perhaps provide a source if you think this is a fact.

Comment: @EJP, also you took my statement out of context, I said: "**To detect inactive client connections** most server applications send out some form of heartbeat or ping message.." This means for protocols that are session based where the server needs to determine if the clients are still connected. HTTP does not have a concept of sessions (hence why this is implemented through other means like cookies) and the servers do not care if the clients are still connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

> `tcp-keepalive` is not applicable as we need to tweak the registry in Windows?

TCP keepalive is an option if you can accept the default timeout of two hours.

> I need a x-platform compatible solution.

TCP keepalive is cross-platform.

> I have read that `recv()` to the connected socket in the server code will return some values from 'that' client such as `0` for socket closed?

it will return zero if the peer closes its socket, and on some platforms if the peer process merely exits without closing it.

> Can I use this to clear off the client socket registration in the server database? Will this work?

Only if you can rely on the peer closing the socket properly.

It seems to me that what you should be doing is debugging the client code so it doesn't crash, and using TCP keepalive as a long-term backup.

You should also be aware that `send()` to a peer that has exited will sooner or later fail with an ECONNRESET error.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so this means either TCP `keepalive` as a long term option, apart from this, if I `send()` to a connected client lets say at regular intervals of time and the client for suppose cannot send data back after 5th `send()`, I can assume that client has closed (properly or with an error)?

Comment: `send()` itself will get an error eventually when TCP times out the sending operation. I'm not a fan of application pings but maybe this is a case for one.